# How can I know if a TSB has been applied to my vehicle?

Tags: abs, service, infiniti, reprogram

I have a 2013 Infiniti JX35 with a brake pedal that is softening when the car is at a full stop. An independent auto shop says that the ABS needs to be reprogrammed by the dealership as described in TSB 378415 (https://www.automd.com/tsb/bulletin_b378415/). The dealership claimed that this TSB did not apply to my vehicle.

How can I figure out if the TSB applies? If it does apply, how can I find out for myself if the reprogramming has been done or not?

Comment: This may be helpful.  https://www.automd.com/tsb/infiniti_m/jx35_mm/2013_y/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the second question:

> How can I figure out if the TSB applies? If it does apply, how can I
>   find out for myself if the reprogramming has been done or not?

Apart from experiencing the fault described by the TSB and *assuming* that is the cause, you cannot unfortunately.

More guess work- if you know the dealership which the previous owner used, they *may* share the service record with you.

I seriously doubt that even high end scan tools can read this information. If Infiniti is like Mercedes (and software is still software), they have proprietary applications for reprogramming modules.

Answer (score 1):

The correct TSB is ITB14-051.

Does your car have intelligent cruise control/forward collision warning?
Is the DTC C1A27 stored in the computer?
Is the brake fluid level normal?

Is the car AWD? was it built before 5/2014?
Is the car FWD? was it built before 8/2014?

If these apply than your car is covered under the TSB.

As to how to check if the fix has been applied. You would need a shop level scantool and to read the ROM calibration number. Then you need to call the dealer and see if they'll give you the corresponding calibration number to verify that the ROM has been updated.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to call the dealer with the VIN and have them check to see if it applies and has been done? They would have this info, as they would be the ones to do the work.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 If the work was done at an independent shop, then other than in the shops system and an invoice there wouldn't be a record. Any shop with a J2534 device or factory scantool can do reflashes per TSBs. Some shops don't though and recommend going to the dealer. Reflashing in general is pretty touchy and can lead to bricked computers if everything isn't 100%.

Comment: I guess I assumed TSB's would only be done by the dealership. I guess maybe I'm thinking of recalls and not specifically TSB's ... huge difference there so I see your point.

Comment: @Paulster2. I made the assumption that Acura dealerships would hold a common database of service records for most/all locations. For Acura and Mercedes it's only per location, from what I've seen.